# difference between confidence interval and prediction interval in the context of regression analysis and predictive modeling

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, data-mining, predictive-models, prediction-interval

When building prediction models, I always see the following concept
1)  Confidence interval  for regression model
2)  Prediction interval
3)  Confidence interval for predicted value
I can understand the third concept, but am not very clear about the first and second one. Are they the same thing, or what are their differences.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what the first thing intends (context might help), but I assume it's intended to be the same as the third thing - a confidence interval for the mean (but perhaps taken at each value of the predictor(s), rather than just a single point in x-space)